# Where does UNIX look for login information? eg where it finds what to do?

Tags: login

So I've been getting more and more into my UNIX system, a mac, and I wanted to know where it goes to execute a log-in. I know where it keeps the passwords and such, but I would like to see the script it runs at log-in. I did find `/usr/bin/login` but neither vim nor nano will show anything that looks like code(eg. it's 90% @ symbols). So if that is the file how can I read it?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/97164/490315 ?

Comment: The "@symbols" you saw mean that `/usr/bin/login` is actually a binary file. You should try looking for its source code in your repos.

Comment: @whirlwin Not exactly, I'm trying to see what Unix does to start up, so then I can get greater knowledge about Unix

Comment: @JosephR. Thanks for telling me that I actually didn't know that, and sorry I'm quite bad a jargon, what would my repos be?

Comment: Despite the fact that OSX is POSIX-compliant and SUS certified, I personally would look in other places for things to learn. For example Linux, BSD or (Open)Solaris. All very easy to install via VM. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: repos = repositories. That would be where your package manager (I'm not sure what its name is on Mac OS) goes to download applications

Comment: Thanks, and I just enjoy looking into things, and since so many computers I use are Unix based I thought it would be fun to look into.

Comment: The graphical login components of OSX aren't open source, so it's unlikely you'll be able to see the source of it (and do you know Objective C?  Because that's likely what its written in).  OSX isn't a great place to start learning about the internals of the OS due to its closed source, try Linux or one of the BSDs.

Comment: The login program is not text: A lot of people/programs call non-text files binary-files, but this is confusing, as all files are binary. Sometimes binary-file refers only to files that the program/person can not read, or understand.

Answer (score 2):

It depends... if you start a console login, a program usually called `getty` (in Fedora Linux, `agetty(8)`) shows the `login:` prompt, asks for the username and passes that to `login(1)`, which gets the user's information, asks for the password and (if successful) sets up the environment and starts a shell for the user. The login program is quite standard, the Linux one is part of the [`util-linux` package](http://git.kernel.org/?p=utils/util-linux/util-linux.git). The FreeBSD version is [here](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/9.1.0/usr.bin/login/) (that is probably nearer the MacOS one than the Linux version).

For a graphical login, there is a greeter program like `xdm(1)` or something more elaborate like `gdm`, which does most of the above, but starts an X session with predefined programs running.

Answer (score 1):

As you are running Mac OSX, you can use [dtrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) [execsnoop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/execsnoop.1m.html) in a terminal to see all commands executed:

```
nohup sudo execsnoop -v > /var/tmp/execsnoop.log &
```

Then logout and login and you'll see what your OS is running.

You might modify this [dtrace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtrace.1.html) script for it to use anonymous tracing and then see all programs executed while your OS is booting.